# VirtualBox: Accessing guest Linux filesystem from host MacOS

Tags: linux, macos, mac, virtualbox, linux-mint

I'm running Linux mint 15 inside a virtualBox on Mac OS (i.e. Mac host, Linux guest). I already know how to share files and access them from the Linux guest, but how can I access the filesystem on the guest linux OS from my Mac??

I'm running:

- VirtualBox Version 4.2.18 r88780
- Linux Mint 15 Olivia xfce
- Mac OS X version 10.8.5

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't using just VirtualBox, you need to use some other file sharing solution, or just use the shared folders feature of VirtualBox and either move the mount point or just move files manually.

Comment: As long as there are no drivers for the file system Linux Mint uses (should be ext4) in Mac OS X, you won't have any luck there. There are ways to mount Virtualbox images, but only if the file system inside it is supported.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is still an open issue for you, but normally I use `sshfs` for Linux - osx file-sharing. sshfs for osx is a google query away.

Comment: Good answer, I voted it up, partially to compensate the incorrect downvote. I suggest to extend your answers next time with references (either by link or by copypasteed text), or at least write longer answers - it helps the moderators to let your answer further without the need to read it :-)